# Как сделать правильный push() в JS?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Через цикл запихиваю в массив данные вида:

```
var names= [];
var fio = "Пупкин №";

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
names.push({ fio: fio + [i]});
}
```

На выходе `document.write(JSON.stringify(names));` получаю массив: `[{"fio":"Пупкин №0"},{"fio":"Пупкин №1"},{"fio":"Пупкин №2"},{"fio":"Пупкин №3"},{"fio":"Пупкин №4"}]`

Как мы видим, fio и Пупкин № находятся в кавычках. соответственно вопрос:

Как сделать так, что бы на выходе получилось `[{fio:"Пупкин №0"},{fio:"Пупкин №1"},{fio:"Пупкин №2"},{fio:"Пупкин №3"},{fio:"Пупкин №4"}]`

Т.е. что бы fio не обвертывалось в кавычки.

Спасибо

Comment: Если на выходе ключ объекта будет без двойных кавычек - это будет не валидный JSON. Если используете функции из объекта `JSON`. Такие как `stringify` то ключ всегда будет в кавычках

Comment: а чем не устраивают кавычки?

Comment: может, почитать про то, что такое формат JSON?

Comment: так и не было ответа зачем это нужно. видимо автора волнует лишь гигантский костыль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю зачем вам это нужно, но вот очень пошлый вариант, который приведет к желаемому результату.

```js
var
  names= [],
  fio = "Пупкин №",
  output = '';
  
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  names.push({ fio: fio + [i]});
}

for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
  output += '{fio:"' + names[j].fio +'"},';
}

alert(output);
```